# update existing option in select list

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say that I have select list with 3 options inside:

```
  <select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
  </select>
```

Now, I want to update one of these options, so i create textfield & button.
The option appear inside the textfield everytime i press on one of the options at the select list.
Can someone direct me what do i need to do?

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding up to the first example that we had this morning [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/T8znS/)

HTML:

```
<select id='myselect'>
   <option value='1'>1</option>
   <option value='2'>2</option>
   <option value='3'>3</option>
</select>
<input type='text' value='1' name='mytext' id='mytext' />
<button value='add' id='addbtn' name='addbtn'>add</button>
<button value='edit' id='editbtn' name='editbtn'>edit</button>
<button value='delete' id='deletebtn' name='deletebtn'>delete</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
var myselect = document.getElementById('myselect');

function createOption() {
    var currentText = document.getElementById('mytext').value;
    var objOption = document.createElement("option");
    objOption.text = currentText;
    objOption.value = currentText;

    //myselect.add(objOption);
    myselect.options.add(objOption);
}

function editOption() {
    myselect.options[myselect.selectedIndex].text = document.getElementById('mytext').value;
    myselect.options[myselect.selectedIndex].value = document.getElementById('mytext').value;
}

function deleteOption() {
    myselect.options[myselect.selectedIndex] = null;
    if (myselect.options.length == 0) document.getElementById('mytext').value = '';
    else document.getElementById('mytext').value = myselect.options[myselect.selectedIndex].text;
}

document.getElementById('addbtn').onclick = createOption;
document.getElementById('editbtn').onclick = editOption;
document.getElementById('deletebtn').onclick = deleteOption;

myselect.onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById('mytext').value = myselect.value;
}
```

Basically i added an edit field that when clicked it'll edit the value and text of the currently selected option, and when you select a new option it'll propogate the textfield with the currently selected option so you can edit it.  Additionally, i also added a delete function since i figure you might need it in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Use jquery [:selected](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) selector and [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method.

```
$('select:selected').val($('input_textbox').val());
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all always give an ID to your input tags. For eg in this case you can do something like: `<select id='myDropDown'>`

Once you have the ID's in place its simple matter of picking up the new value from textbox and inserting it into the dropdown:

Eg:

```
// Lets assume the textbox is called 'myTextBox'
// grab the value in the textbox
 var textboxValue = document.getElementById('myTextBox').value;

// Create a new DOM element to be inserted into Select tag
 var newOption = document.createElement('option');
 newOption.text = textboxValue;
 newOption.value = textboxValue;

// get handle to the dropdown
 var dropDown = document.getElementById('myDropDown');

// insert the new option tag into the dropdown.
 try {
   dropDown.add(newOption, null); // standards compliant; doesn't work in some versions of IE
 }
 catch(ex) {
   dropDown.add(newOption); // IE only
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is a pure js example using your markup.

**EDIT**
After rereading your question Im not sure if you wanted the option to update when a user clicked the button or not.. To just put the option into an input you can do this.

```
var select = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0],
    input = document.getElementById("inputEl");

select.onchange = function(){
     input.value = this[this.selectedIndex].text;
}
```

To update the option to what the user typed in is below.

http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/24cHN/6/

**Markup**

```
<select>
     <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
</select>
<br/>
<input type="text" id="inputEl"/>
<button id="button">Update</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
var select = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0],
    input = document.getElementById("inputEl"),
    button = document.getElementById("button");

select.onchange = function(){
    input.value = this[this.selectedIndex].text;

    var selected = this,
        selectedIndex = this.selectedIndex;

        button.onclick = function(){
          selected[selectedIndex].text = input.value;
    }  
}
```